# Handling null result

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, linq-to-sql

I have a db request that could return `null`:

```
Pony MyPony = db.Pony.Where(p => p.PonyOwnerId == user.UserId).First();
```

If there is no row in my db, there is an error message.

How to accept an empty query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx)

```
Pony myPony = db.Pony.Where(p => p.PonyOwnerId == user.UserId).FirstOrDefault();

if (myPony == null) 
{ 
    .. 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write:

```
Pony myPony = db.Pony.Where(p => p.PonyOwnerId == user.UserId).FirstOrDefault();
if( myPony != null ) {
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var MyPony = db.Pony.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PonyOwnerId != null && p.PonyOwnerId == user.UserId);
```

or

```
var MyPony = db.Pony.Where(p => p.PonyOwnerId != null && p.PonyOwnerId == user.UserId).FirstOrDefault();
```

or

```
if (db.Pony.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PonyOwnerId != null && p.PonyOwnerId == user.UserId) != null)
{
 //Do stuff
}
```